# for loop with divided list

Tags: javascript, for-loop

There is a list of 78 items:

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li> 78 </li> 
</ul>
```

which I want to divide into blocks of 10 - 10 each.

Each block will have 10 items.

Result will be 7 blocks with 10 items and the 8th block with 8 items.

```
<ul>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li> 10 </li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li> 11 </li>
    <li> 12 </li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li> 20 </li>
</ul><br>
.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
<ul>
    <li> 71 </li>
    <li> 72 </li>
    .
    .
    .
    <li> 78 </li>
</ul>
```

Suggest a logic

Comment: That's not really how SO works. You need to provide some code that you've already tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have the list elements in an array or anything like that?

Comment: Please take a [tour around the website](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @BrunoToffolo: Yes, `document.querySelectorAll("ul > li")` :-)

Answer (score 1):

suppose that ul has id `list` :

```
var oldUL=document.getElementById('list');
var l = oldUL.children;
for(var i=0;i<l.length;i+=10){
 var newUL = document.createElement('ul');
 for(var s=0;s<10 && s<l.length;s++){
  newUL.appendChild(l[s]);
 }
 document.body.appendChild(newUl);
}
document.removeChild(oldUL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried with own logic.
Working code link is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hammerStrike/byn4Lv9a/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var listHtml = $('#list ul').html(),
    listLength = $('#list ul li').length;

var _html = '',l = listLength, helpAgent = l, counter = 1,_newList='';

for(var i = 1 ; i <= Math.ceil(l/10) ; i++){         
    var lim = 10;       
    if(helpAgent == (l%10)){
        lim = helpAgent;
    }
    helpAgent -= 10;

    _newList += "<ul>";
    for(var j = 1 ; j <= lim ; j++){ 
        _newList += "<li>" + $($('#list ul li')[counter-1]).html() + "</li>";
        counter++;
    }  
    _newList += "</ul>";
}
$("#result").html(_newList);});
```

This will work for 2 digit limit (here 78) I used %10 to get remainder of 2 digits number.